# Implement a condition on a query JMESPATH

Tags: json, azure, powershell, jmespath

I have this query which bring me the expiring dates of the keyvault's secret, I have to bring the dates that are less than 30 days

```
az keyvault secret show \
 --vault name "$keyvault" \
 --name "$secret" \
 --query "attributes.expires" - o tsv
```

How can I implement something like

```
--query "attributes.expires < 30 days" - o tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to make the date computation in JMESPath, but you could perfectly let PowerShell do it, with the [`Get-Date` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date).

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(30) | Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK
```

For the JMESPath query part, you have to know that a filter can only be applied to an array, not to an object, which is what you seems to have.
You can overcome this, though, using the function [`to_array`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array) on your object, and, then, use a [pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions) to get only the first item of the array – `| [0]`.

So, if the unfiltered JSON return of the Azure client looks like

```json
{
  "attributes": {
    "expires": "2022-07-30T00:00:00+00:00"
  }
}
```

Then, this should be your query

```
--query "to_array(attributes)[?
  expires < '$((Get-Date).AddDays(30) | Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK)'
] | [0].expires"
```